# TreeNode click vs TreeView click

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes, contextmenustrip

I have a TreeView and I need two things.

- A Right-Click support if I click on a specific node.
- A Right-Click support if I click anywhere else on the tree (where there is no nodes).

The two options would both give me a different `ContextMenuStrip`.
My two program now supports both type of clicks like this.

Specific Node click :

```
var someNode = e.Node.Tag as SomeNode;
if (someNode != null)
{
   someContextMenu.Show(someTree, e.Location);
   return;
}
```

Anywhere on the tree click :

[image]

The problem is that the `Anywhere on the tree click` event **will fire before checking if I clicked on the node** or on a blank spot from the `TreeView`. 
Any Idea how I could change that behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about winforms.

You can use the [TreeView.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6sb88bz.aspx) method which return a [TreeViewHitTestInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewhittestinfo.aspx) where you can know if you hit a node or not.

Comment: oups forgot the tag sorry. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        TreeViewHitTestInfo info = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
        treeView1.SelectedNode = info.Node;

        if (info.Node == null)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
        else
        {
            contextMenuStrip2.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }
}
```

Or the mouse up event depending on your needs. Also you can use GetNodeAt(e.Location) instead of the TreeViewHitTestInfo class.